# clang optimized code in wrong way

Tags: c, macos, compilation, clang

Here is part of code:

```
static uint32_t mp4_atom_containers[] = {
    ATOM('m', 'o', 'o', 'v'), 
    ATOM('t', 'r', 'a', 'k'), 
    ATOM('m', 'd', 'i', 'a'),
    ATOM('m', 'i', 'n', 'f'),
    ATOM('s', 't', 'b', 'l')
};

typedef struct {
    uint32_t size;
    uint32_t type;
    u_char data[0];
} __packed mp4_atom_hdr_t;

static ngx_int_t f(mp4_file_t *mp4f, mp4_atom_t *atom)
{
    ngx_uint_t i;
    uint32_t atom_size;

    ngx_log_debug1(NGX_LOG_DEBUG_HTTP, mp4f->log, 0, "f:: type: %i", atom->hdr->type);

    if (atom->hdr->type == ATOM('t', 'r', 'a', 'k'))
        mp4f->trak = atom;
    else if (atom->hdr->type == ATOM('s', 't', 's', 'z'))
        mp4f->stsz = (mp4_atom_stsz_t *)atom->hdr;
    else if (atom->hdr->type == ATOM('s', 't', 's', 'c'))
        mp4f->stsc = (mp4_atom_stsc_t *)atom->hdr;
    else if (atom->hdr->type == ATOM('m', 'v', 'h', 'd'))
        mp4f->mvhd = (mp4_atom_mvhd_t *)atom->hdr;

    // point #1
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(mp4_atom_containers); i++) {
        if (atom->hdr->type == mp4_atom_containers[i]) 
            goto found;
    }

    return 0;

found:
    atom_size = be32toh(atom->hdr->size) - sizeof(*hdr);
    // rest of the code

    return 0;
}
```

Here is binary code from clang, disassembled with Hopper:

```
00000001000750c2         mov        rdx, qword [ds:r13+0x28]                    ; XREF=_mp4_parse_atom+35
00000001000750c6         mov        eax, dword [ds:rdx+4]
00000001000750c9         cmp        eax, 'srak'
00000001000750ce         jg         0x1000750e0

00000001000750d0         cmp        eax, 'stsc'
00000001000750d5         jne        0x1000750f0

00000001000750d7         mov        qword [ds:r14+0x140], rdx                   ; mp4f->stsc = (mp4_atom_stsz_t *)atom->hdr;
00000001000750de         jmp        0x10007510e

00000001000750e0         cmp        eax, 'stsz'                                 ; XREF=_mp4_parse_atom+78
00000001000750e5         jne        0x100075100

00000001000750e7         mov        qword [ds:r14+0x138], rdx                   ; mp4f->stsz = (mp4_atom_stsc_t *)atom->hdr;
00000001000750ee         jmp        0x10007510e

00000001000750f0         cmp        eax, 'mvhd'                                 ; XREF=_mp4_parse_atom+85
00000001000750f5         jne        0x10007510e

00000001000750f7         mov        qword [ds:r14+0x130], rdx                   ; mp4f->mvhd = (mp4_atom_mvhd_t *)atom->hdr;
00000001000750fe         jmp        0x10007510e

0000000100075100         cmp        eax, 'trak'                                 ; XREF=_mp4_parse_atom+101
0000000100075105         jne        0x10007510e

0000000100075107         mov        qword [ds:r14+0x128], r13                   ; mp4f->trak = atom;

000000010007510e         mov        rbx, r14                                    ; XREF=_mp4_parse_atom+94, _mp4_parse_atom+110, _mp4_parse_atom+117, _mp4_parse_atom+126, _mp4_parse_atom+133
0000000100075111         mov        eax, dword [ds:rdx]
0000000100075113         bswap      eax
0000000100075115         xor        r12d, r12d
0000000100075118         add        eax, 0xfffffff8
000000010007511b         mov        qword [ss:rbp+var_38], rax                 ; atom_size = be32toh(atom->hdr->size) - sizeof(*hdr);
000000010007511f         je         0x10007527f                                ; point #2

0000000100075125         lea        rax, qword [ds:r13+0x18]
0000000100075129         mov        qword [ss:rbp+var_48], rax
000000010007512d         xor        r14d, r14d
0000000100075130         mov        r15, rdx
0000000100075133         jmp        0x100075144
0000000100075135         nop        word [cs:rax+rax]
; other code
```

For some reason clang removed or optimized in wrong way check at point #1. In disassembled code it must go to point #2 if type is not one of the `mp4_atom_containers` types.

Comment: I can't really see how the disassembly corresponds to the source code, so I'm going to assume you can - are you're saying it's treating the loop as `for(i = 0; true; i++)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mp4_atom_containers[i]` in the for loop accesses out of bounds, which invokes **undefined behaviour**.
The compiler is allowed to optimize the loop condition in that way.

```
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(mp4_atom_containers); i++)
```

should be

```
for (i = 0; i < sizeof mp4_atom_containers / sizeof *mp4_atom_containers; i++)
```

`sizeof(mp4_atom_containers)` is the size of the whole array in bytes, but `sizeof mp4_atom_containers / sizeof *mp4_atom_containers` is the number of elements in the array.

The compiler is allowed to assume that `i` will never be 5, because that would be an access out of bounds and so `i` will always be smaller than `sizeof(mp4_atom_containers)` (which is most likely 20) and so it is an endless loop.

Comment: @immibis thanks, I added something due to your comment.

Comment: So compiler see that loop is endless and just remove it?

Comment: I meant to say it can assume the 6th (not 5th) element will never be accessed, and so it can assume one of the first 5 (not 4) elements matches.

Comment: @immibis am I right this is defined in language specification or just a specific compiler behaviour?

Comment: @JohnTracid The language specification says that you may not access the 6th element of a 5-element array. Once you try to access the 6th element of a 5-element array you are beyond the scope of the language specification.

Comment: @immibis so another compiler may leave this as it is and allow crash here, right?

Comment: @JohnTracid Yes. A third compiler might decide to let it work except on Tuesdays.

Comment: @JohnTracid It is undefined behaviour. Another compiler is allowed to do the same thing, but it is also allowed to do something complete different.

Comment: The compiler is smart but its shrewdness is counterproductive.  It would be more useful to warn the programmer about what looks like probable undefined behavior.

Comment: The compiler should apply Mark Twain's principle: *do not suspect malice when plain stupidity explains the situation*.  In other words: *if it looks contorted, it is more likely a mistake than a smart hack.*

Comment: @chqrlie Yes, I think same way. Compiler changed program flow here instead of leaving things as they are. Yes, I will have crash but I will see that crash. In case of clang this code continue to execute like nothing happen.

Comment: @JohnTracid: it is very unlikely you would get a crash from this mistake.  The array will end up in the middle of the data segment, reading past its end is most likely harmless, you may just get false positives.  I'm not sure `valgrind` would detect this either.